# Limit definition of a derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

If I have a continuously differentiable function $u(\theta)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, is the following true? $$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0}\frac{u(\theta+\delta)-u(\theta)}{\delta}=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0}\frac{u(\theta)-u(\theta-\delta)}{\delta}=u’(\theta)$$

I understand that the left-most expression is the limit definition of the derivative. I am not sure about the second. What exactly does the second define? Thank you.

Comment: The second is also the derivative. To see it, replace $\delta$ with $-\delta$.

Answer (score 4):

The second part is the first with the substitution $\theta_1=\theta+\delta$. Since $\delta\to 0$, we have that $\theta_1\to\theta$ so the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding the slope between the points:

$(,u())$ and $(+,u(+))$

as  approaches 0 (getting the two points as infinitely close as possible),

We are finding the slope between the points:

$(-,u(-))$ and $(,u())$

As long as u() is differentiable, then this will calculate the same slope as both $(+,u(+))$ and $(-,u(-))$ as  approaches 0, are both equally infinitely close to the point $(,u())$.